# How to unmap a modifier?

Tags: xkb

I'm trying to swap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for group 1. I have this in xkb_symbols:

```
      replace key <BKSP>
      {  
         symbols[Group1] = [ Caps_Lock ],
         symbols[Group2] = [ BackSpace ], 
         actions[Group1] = [ LockMods(modifiers=Lock) ],
         actions[Group2] = [ NoAction() ]
      };
      replace key <CAPS>
      {  
         symbols[Group1] = [ BackSpace ],
         symbols[Group2] = [ Caps_Lock ], 
         actions[Group1] = [ NoAction() ],
         actions[Group2] = [ LockMods(modifiers=Lock) ]
      };
```

However, when I compile this, the following shows up:

```
modifier_map Lock { <BKSP> };
```

This causes <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to still toggle caps lock in group 1 in some applications.

Is there a way to prevent this? `modifier_map none { <BKSP> }` doesn't work.